# PHP: split array into chunks based off of custom function?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array or arrays:

```
    $bigArray = array(
        array(
            id = 3,
            text = "Hello World"
            ),
        array(
            id = 3,
            text = "Taco"
            ),
         array(
             id = 10,
             text = "Foo"
            ),
         array(
             id = 10,
             text = "Bar"
            ),
         array(
             id = 10,
             text = "dogfood"
            )
      );
```

I'd like to be able to split the array of arrays up into multiple arrays based off of the id numbers like so:

```
    $arrayOne = array(
        array(
            id = 3,
            text = "Hello World"
            ),
        array(
            id = 3,
            text = "Taco"
            )
        );

    $arrayTwo = array(
         array(
             id = 10,
             text = "Foo"
            ),
         array(
             id = 10,
             text = "Bar"
            ),
         array(
             id = 10,
             text = "dogfood"
            )
      );
```

The cloest PHP function I can find that does this is `array_chunk()` but it works only off of a numerical index. Are there any similar functions that make the chunk splitting decisions based off of a custom written function instead?

I know I can write a custom function to iterate through the bigArray and do this all manually, but I wanted to ask first if there were any native methods first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating array using the `id` attribute.

```
$group = array();
foreach($bigArray as $ar){
    $group[$ar['id']][]=$ar;
}
$chunks = array_values($group);
```

Now if you run `extract($chunks,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'Array_');` You'll get array variables like `$Array_0`, `$Array_1` etc.